# What is a default return type of method in Flutter(Dart)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

If I don't write any return type in method of Flutter then which is default return type ? For Example

```
getMyValue(){

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default return type is `dynamic`

Comment: also, if you wonder how it `guesses` the right type, here is the docs for that: https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system

Answer (score 1):

In general, the type of something that isn't explicitly specified and that isn't inferred is `dynamic`.

Examples:

```dart
var x; // Same as `dynamic x`
List listOfDynamic; // Same as `List<dynamic>`
var anotherListOfDynamic = [];
var mapOfDynamicToDynamic = {}; // Same as `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

foo(x) { } // Same as `dynamic foo(dynamic x)`
```

If you're in doubt, if enter some code https://dartpad.dartlang.org/, moving the text cursor next to an identifier will tell you what it is.

Answer (score 0):

First, it tries to infer the type, and only if it fails it uses the `dynamic` type.
Please read the docs on [Type inference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference)